# Gnuplot: How to plot each line from a file as a seperate figure?

Tags: gnuplot

I know the command to plot circle in gnuplot:

```
plot 'circle.txt' using 1:2:3 with circles
```

Suppose if `circle.txt` contains `n` lines and each line contains (`centerX`, `centerY`, `radius`) of different circles, e.g.:

```
#x  y   radius
0   0   1
1   1   2
2   2   3
```

How can I generate `n` images containing `n` different circles - one image per line?

Answer (score 2):

This will work with **gnuplot 4.4** and higher:

```
gnuplot> n = "`awk 'END {print NR}' < circle.txt`"
gnuplot> i=0; while i<n{set term wxt i; plot 'circle.txt' every ::i::i using 1:2:3 with circles; i=i+1}
```

Explanation:

- `` "`awk 'END {print NR}' < circle.txt`" `` to determine the number of rows in the file
  (*Warning:* This does not work on a Windows 32-bit system)
- `i=0` to set the counter for the while loop
- `while i<n` loop through the rows of the file
- `{ }` while-clause has to be in curly braces
- `set term wxt i` this portion opens the new window for each plot
- separate commands by `;`
- `plot 'circle.txt' every ::i::i using 1:2:3 with circles` this plots just the `i`th line of the file. [More information on plotting specific lines can be found here.](http://xmodulo.com/2012/10/how-to-plot-using-specific-rows-of-data-file-with-gnuplot.html)
- `i=i+1` increment the counter

Comment: @user69910 Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark (✓) next to the voting buttons or commenting on what does not work for you.