# Read function coefficients from file

Tags: gnuplot

Say I have the following file:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

I would like to have gnuplot plot 3 polynomials of the form a*x^2 + b*x +c, using the file values as coefficients. Performing this directly, I would do:

```
plot x**2+2*x+3, 4*x**2+5*x+6, 7*x**2+8*x+9
```

But I would like to do this programatically, for an arbitrary number of lines in the input file.

I think I might be close with code inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16842201/3371623):

```
n= "`awk 'END {print NR}' < test.dat`"
i=0
while i<n{
f(a,b,c,x)=a*x**2+b*x+c
plot 'test.dat' every ::i::i using f($1,$2,$3,x)
}
```

But this fails with `undefined variable: x`

Comment: With the syntax `plot 'test.dat' ...` you plot a data file, and not a function of x. So the variable x isn't defined. You could also have a look at [Plotting a function directly from a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15007620/2604213). In any case, there isn't a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem for ages and finally I managed to find a solution.
It requires a creative use of the `stats` function to assign the values from the file to the variables and a couple of `do for [...]` loops to store some commands in a temp file

```
filename = "InputFileName.dat"
stats filename nooutput
nlines = STATS_records-1
set print "temp.gnuplot"
do for [i=0:nlines] {\
  print sprintf("stats filename every ::%i::%i using (a%i=$1,b%i=$2,c%i=$3,0):(0) nooutput",i,i,i,i,i)}
set print
load "temp.gnuplot"
set print "temp.gnuplot"
do for [i=1:nlines] {print sprintf("replot  a%i*x**2 + b%i*x + c%i",i,i,i)}
plot a0*x**2 + b0*x +c0
load "temp.gnuplot"
set print
```

Change the `filename` variable as you need. You can remove the temp file once you are finished with a system call like this `! rm temp.gnuplot`.

I know is not particularly elegant and I especially don't like the use of a temp file, if somebody knows how to execute a string variable I'd be happy to know. But hey, it works (even under Windows)!

Edit: forgot to credit [thse](http://gnuplot.10905.n7.nabble.com/reading-file-data-into-variables-td922.html) for the input.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread but thanks to the previous answer, I can propose an upgraded version using strings instead of a temp file. That one, there is no need to bother deleting the useless temp file afterwards.

```
filename = "InputFileName.dat"
stats filename nooutput

nlines = STATS_records-1

paramstr(N) = sprintf("stats filename every ::%i::%i using (a%i=$1,b%i=$2,c%i=$3,0):(0) nooutput",N,N,N,N,N)
do for [i=0:nlines] {
    eval(paramstr(i))
}

plotstr = "p "
do for [i=0:nlines] {
    plotstr = plotstr . sprintf("a%i*x**2 + b%i*x + c%i%s",i,i,i,(i == nlines) ? "" : ", ")
}

eval(plotstr)
```

Maybe that some `set xrange` and `set yrange` tuning will be necessary to look at what you are interested in though.

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [Plotting a function directly from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15007620/7295599), however, with more parameters and in several lines.
At the time of OP's question there were no arrays in gnuplot, but you can simply store your values in a string and address them via some functions using `word()` and `real()`, check `help word` and `help real`).

There is no need for `awk` (as in the link), no temporary files (solution of @Joseph D'Arimathea) and no extra loops or `eval()` (solution of @afagot).

**Data:** `SO26680694.dat`

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### extract multiple parameters from a datafile
reset

FILE = "SO26680694.dat"

set datafile separator ','
myParams = ''
stats FILE u (myParams = myParams.sprintf(' %g %g %g', $1, $2, $3),0) nooutput

myParam(s,i) = real(word(myParams,(s-1)*3+i))
a(s) = myParam(s,1)
b(s) = myParam(s,2)
c(s) = myParam(s,3)

f(x,a,b,c) = a*x**2 + b*x + c

plot for [i=1:3] f(x,a(i),b(i),c(i)) title sprintf("%gx^2 + %gx + %g",a(i),b(i),c(i))
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]